# How do I set an dependency property override just once?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to implement a Button in WPF which uses Ninject to get a command object, that part works ok. When this button is instantiated the first time, everything works flawlessly.  However any subsequent activity with this type causes the issue shown below:

```
internal class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
       SetOverrides();
    }

    public void SetOverrides()
    {
        var controller = App.kernel.Get<ICommand>("SomeCommand");
        Button.CommandProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                {
                    DefaultValue = controller
                }
             );
        Button.CommandParameterProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
             {
                 DefaultValue = Tag
             }
            );
    }
}
```

**The Issue:**
The error that I see is this: "PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'MyButton'."

**The Cause:**
  The CTOR is being called more than once due to there being more than one of these buttons in the application.

The options I have are:

1. Create a static bool value saying "already set" and use that to avoid the issue.
2. Attempt to check the values themselves to see if they are already set.
3. If I move this code over to the app.cs file I then have a problem with this line of code because the value TAG is not contained in the app.cs class.  If I knew how to make this code say "Bind to the tag property of any button instance I'd have it, but I don't know how to do that.  I also don't know if registering this over in App.cs is a good thing or not.

   ```
   Button.CommandParameterProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
             {
                DefaultValue = Tag
             }
    );
   ```

Please advise..

Comment: Can you make your `SetOverrides` method `static`? Then call it from a static constructor rather than an instance constructor.

Comment: @StevenRands the problem with that is Ninject might not be ready yet for the `App.kernel.Get<ICommand>("SomeCommand");` (that's why I deleted my answer). I think you may just have to use option 1.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That does not invalidate your answer. As clearly stated on MSDN, calls to OverrideMetadata should only be performed within the static constructors. Even with option 1, there would still be the problem that the default value of the CommandParameter would be set to the current value of the Tag property of the first Button. Thus, subsequently created MyButton instances would all get this Tag value as the default of their CommandParameter.

Comment: @clemens Of course that's it put the overrides into Static CTORs, thanks I didn't even think about that one!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking this whole thing as this was final solution:

```
internal class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        this.Loaded += MyButton_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyButton_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.IsInDesignMode)
        {
            var controller = App.kernel.Get<ICommand>("SomeCommand");
            this.CommandParameter = Tag;
            this.Command = controller;
        }
    }
}
```

Wow! And thanks to everyone for helping out...